# Copy & Paste Bitmap from .Net Code to Powerpoint including Position

Tags: .net, position, powerpoint, shapes, clipboard

It is possible to add a bitmap to the clipboard and it can be pasted in a PowerPoint application. However, it is placed at an arbitrary postition.

On the other hand, if I copy a shape element in PowerPoint and paste it, e.g., in another slide, the position remains the same as the initial shaped. Thus, PowerPoint can store the position in the clipboard, too.

I guess i have to put additional information / an higher object to the clipboad. How can I do that?

Comment: Where is the original bitmap coming from? If from a program other than PPT, there are no PPT coordinates to impose on it once pasted.

Comment: I want to create the bitmap programatically (or load bmp) and place it at a known position, e.g., [300, 400] from upper left corner of slide to upper left corner of bitmap, with size [200, 300]

Comment: After pasting in the image, set its .Top, .Left, .Height and .Width properties to anything  you like. The coordinate system starts at top left of the slide; measurements are in Points (72 points per inch)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it yet. Asume I have a HelloWorld  .Net Application. One Button, that reads an Image from file and puts it in the clipboard (i know it is intended to be pasted in the upper left corner of any powerpoint slide). I switch to PowerPoint and use "Paste". I have no "hook" to programmatically set the top and left to zero.

Comment: After pasting in an image, you can get a reference to it via the current slide's .Shapes collection. Assuming a reference to the slide in oSl you can use oSl.Shapes(oSl.Shapes.Count) to return a reference to the just-pasted shape.  Then oSh.Left and oSh.Top will let  you set the position. OTOH, why use the clipboard at all? You can just add the picture as a new shape directly:  set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddPicture2( "filename", , , 0, 0, -1, -1)  That'll put it at 0 top, 0 left, at its "natural" size. You can then use oSh.Height and oSh.Width to change the size if needed.